# Is the bcrypt compare time/complexity the same as the hashing function

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, authentication, bcrypt

Is the slow/computationally expensive part of bcrypt just the hash generating part, or is the comparison/compare function which verifies the password against the hash also just as slow?

For example lets say: would generating a user password hash when they register take the same amount of time as verifying their password when they log in?

Answer (score 0):

To have some resistance to password generation attacks, [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) uses iteration on Key expansion of [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) cipher. The number iterations are defined as the powers of 2, at in can go from 2^4 to 2^31. It also uses salt against the [Rainbow Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

When a new user registered, the server takes the key and Bcrypt it then stores.

When a user wants to log-in, user sends the password to the server, and the server again Bcrypt it to compare with the stored result.

As a result, the comparison also requires a Bcrypt run this implies they will have almost the same timing.